# I create a program,and it has a TypeError:"'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Tags: python

```
numberOfArray1 = [1, 2, 5, 3]
numberOfArray2 = [4, 1, 3, 2]

allNumber = []

for array1 in numberOfArray1:
    for array2 in numberOfArray2:
        for i in numberOfArray1:
            for j in numberOfArray2:
                addedNumber = array1[i] + array2[j]
                allNumber.append(addedNumber)

print allNumber
```

Comment: Why are you looping at 4 levels? `array1` is already a number, so you are essentially doing `1[i] + 1[j]`.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You need to read the question guide.

Comment: Why don't you accept an answer? Click the checkmark below any answer's vote signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
for array1 in numberOfArray1:
```

iterates array1 through values of 1, 2, 5, and 3.  Your reference to it later

```
addedNumber = array1[i] + array2[j]
```

is trying to treat array1 as an array; but it isn't.  It's an integer, and cannot be subscripted like that.  That's what 'int has no attribute getitem' means.

Answer (score 0):

So do like that:

```
n1 = [1, 2, 5, 3]
n2 = [4, 1, 3, 2]
n = []
for i in range(0, len(n1)):
    n.append(n1[i] + n2[i])
print n
```